# Trigger on account if 'DUNS no.' field on Account , then make a real-time callout to data.com to fetch the details and populate on Account

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices, callout, data.com

list of fields to be auto populated whenever Duns number on account matches with the Duns number of Data.com.
AnnualRevenue, City, CompanyId,Country, Description, DunsNumber, Fax, Industry etc.

My code is not exact enough to run , Help me out with class and trigger.

```
trigger DunTrig on Account (before Insert) {

 if (Trigger.IsBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {

        private String createAccounts(List<DatacloudCompany> ddcCompanies) {
        Map<String, Account> accountMap = new Map<String, Account>();
        for (DatacloudCompany dc : ddcCompanies){
            accountMap.put(dc.CompanyId, new Account(AccountSource='Data.com', AnnualRevenue=dc.AnnualRevenue,
                                                     BillingCity=dc.city, ShippingCity=dc.city, BillingCountry=dc.Country,
                                                     ShippingCountry=dc.Country, Description=dc.Description, DunsNumber=dc.DunsNumber,
                                                     Fax=dc.Fax, Industry=dc.Industry, NaicsCode=dc.NaicsCode, NaicsDesc=dc.NaicsDesc,
                                                     Name=dc.Name, NumberOfEmployees=dc.NumberOfEmployees, Ownership=dc.Ownership,
                                                     Phone=dc.Phone, Sic=dc.Sic, SicDesc=dc.SicDesc, Site=dc.Site, BillingState=dc.State,
                                                     ShippingState=dc.State, BillingStreet=dc.Street, ShippingStreet=dc.Street,
                                                     TickerSymbol=dc.TickerSymbol, Tradestyle=dc.TradeStyle, Website=dc.Website,
                                                     YearStarted=dc.YearStarted, BillingPostalCode=dc.Zip, ShippingPostalCode=dc.Zip));
        }

       if (accountMap.size() > 0) {
            insert accountMap.values();
        }
            for (String ddcId : accountMap.keySet()) {
            DCC dcc = currentPage.get(ddcId);
            dcc.setAccountId(accountMap.get(ddcId).id);
            dcc.setRenderBox('false');
        }
        return null;
    }       
         (AccountSource=Data.com) datacopy = new (AccountSource=Data.com)();
        List<Id> accountIdList = new List<Id>();
        for(Account acc:trigger.new){
            if (datacopy.DunsNumber!= null){
        //statement to check if duns number gets matched with data.com duns number  
         accountIdList.add(thisAccount.Id);
    }
    }
         if(!accountIdList.isEmpty()){

        datacopy.name = acc.name;
        datacopy.AnnualRevenue = acc.AnnualRevenue;
        datacopy.City=acc.City;
        datacopy.CompanyId=acc.CompanyId;
        datacopy.Country=acc.Country;
        datacopy.Description=acc.Description;
        datacopy.DunsNumber=acc.DunsNumber;
        datacopy.Fax=acc.Fax;
        datacopy.Industry=acc.Industry;
 }   
            insert datacopy ;  
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: I think this is coming in winter17, and I think it will be included, doesn't seem from release notes that any separate license is required.  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_datacom_company_info_accounts.htm

Comment: you are declaring a method `createAccounts` inside a trigger - this is not supported and will not compile. Method calls have to be to methods in separate classes (in this context, sometimes called a trigger handler

Comment: Can Someone write a trigger for this Requirement ??